# Why can't I keep multiple Kerberos tickets

Tags: kerberos

I currently want to ssh into two different realms. However, whenever I generate a ticket for 1 realm using `pkinit`, I lose the ticket I've generated for the other realm.

Why is this & how can I fix it?